# AngularJS: Run Code when Controller is initialized

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does the following code not work? I want the $scope.init() function to run on startup. What is the correct way to run code on controller initialization?

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.init();

    $scope.init = function() {
        ...
    };

});
```

Comment: try put the `init()` after the function?

Comment: `$scope.init()` does not exist from where you are calling it. Call it after setting it, i.e. first `$scope.init = function...` and *then* `$scope.init()`. And you may even not need to put `init()` in scope, running it inline may suffice.

Comment: already tried, doesn't make any difference

Comment: can you set up plunk to reproduce bug?

Answer (score 1):

You try to call init() before it has been defined. If you switch it, it works as you can see in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gjcotq1y/2/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.init = function() {
        alert('Message');
    };
    $scope.init();
    $scope.message = 'Test message';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also define init in the controller as you do:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        ...
    };
});
```

And then call it from the markup:

```
<body ng-init='init()'>
...
</body>
```